# gaussian curvature in isotherm parameterization

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Consider an isothermic parameterization with metric
$$(g_{ij}) = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^2\end{bmatrix}$$
with $\lambda = \lambda(u^1,u^2)>0$. Then the gaussian curvature can be calculated by
$$K=\frac{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2}{\lambda^4} -\frac{\lambda_{11}+\lambda_{22}}{\lambda^4}$$

I know that I can get the curvature as the determinant of the Weingarten map or as the quotient of the determinant of the second and first fundamental form, but I don't quite know how I can get to this just from the given metric.

Can anyone point me to the right direction with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need the [Gauss equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature), most conveniently in an orthogonal parametrization. See most any differential geometry text, including [my own](http://math.uga.edu/%7Eshifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) :)